# tooltipster.js: Tooltip getting overlayed on one another

Tags: tooltipster

Here's the JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/68umt5b3/

As you notice, tooltips are getting changed, but they overlay on one another. Removing '`multiple: true`' helps, but my MAC gets overloaded and browser crashes, saying:

> Tooltipster: one or more tooltips are already attached to this
>   element: ignoring. Use the "multiple" option to attach more tooltips.

I only need one tooltipster shown at the time. How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `content` method to update the content of the tooltip, or destroy it and create a new one.